# Wordpress, How to get a list of terms outside of the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy setup called "albums", and a new album can be added to this so when a song is posted the user can select what album it belongs to.

I understand how to get the specified album in a loop, but I need to just get a basic list of all the albums now and not sure how to do this.

I have tried get_the_terms_list() and get_the_terms, but these both require a post ID, when I just need a list seperate from the post ID.

UPDATE: I found you can do get_taxonomies();  but this just returns "albums", when I need to get whatever was added to the "albums"

Comment: You may want to look at taxonomy questions on the WordPress Stack Exchange as well: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[get_the_term_list()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) might be what you're after

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted. It seems that get_the_term_list() specifically is NOT designed for use outside the loop. Sure if any post ID is passed to it, a list of terms associated with that post for the given taxonomy will be returned. I think the OP actually wants get_terms as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

With get_terms() (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), all you have to specify is the custom taxonomy (plus some arguments if you'd like).